# How to Set Table VAlign and First Row Bolding in Word VBA Style?

Tags: vba, formatting, ms-word

I have a basic [TableStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195508.aspx) laid out as follows:

```
Sub NewTableStyle()
 Dim StyTbl As Style

 Set StyTbl = ActiveDocument.Styles.Add(Name:="PhaseTable", Type:=wdStyleTypeTable)

 With StyTbl.Table
    .Alignment = wdAlignRowLeft

    With .Condition(wdFirstRow)
        With .Borders(wdBorderBottom)
            .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            .Visible = True
            .LineWidth = wdLineWidth150pt
        End With
        With .Borders(wdBorderTop)
            .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            .Visible = True
            .LineWidth = wdLineWidth150pt
        End With
    End With

 End With
End Sub
```

But I want to expand on it, applying the following to all cells:

- font: "Times New Roman", size 12.
- vertical alignment: middle

...and the following to the first row only:

- bold

I think I can add something like:

```
 With StyTbl.Font
    .Size = 12
    .Name = "Times New Roman"
 End With
```

To the end of my subroutine to apply the following properties to the entire table.  However, I can't seem to figure out the selective first row bolding or the vertical alignment.

I know it is probably possible as I can modify the Excel default styles to have these options in the GUI.  How do I set those options in the VBA `Style` which I plan to apply to tables?

Comment: If you want to apply styles to the first row only do it inside your `With .Condition(wdFirstRow) ...  End With` block.

Comment: Right, my above example uses that... the issue is I'm not seeing any member of `StyTbl.Table.Condition(wdFirstRow)` that leads to `.Font.bold`.  Do you know how exactly to call that to get to `.Font`?  Or are you saying perhaps I don't have to?  Are you suggesting I do something like: `StyTbl.Table.Condition(wdFirstRow) StyTable.Font.Bold = True End With`?  Trying that now...

Comment: EDIT:  If I set `StyTbl.Table.Condition(wdFirstRow) StyTable.Font.Bold = True End With`, that applies bold to the entire table, not just the first row.  However, if I set `StyTbl.Table.Condition(wdFirstRow).Font.Bold = True` that does work... can you post that as a solution?  For some reason the `StyTbl.Table.Condition(wdFirstRow)` wasn't initially showing its members, so I missed the somewhat obvious fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `.Font` of the `.Condition(wdFirstRow)` to set the different settings you need:

```
Sub NewTableStyle()
    Dim StyTbl As Style

    Set StyTbl = ActiveDocument.Styles.Add(Name:="PhaseTable", Type:=wdStyleTypeTable)

    With StyTbl.Table
        .Alignment = wdAlignRowLeft

        With .Condition(wdFirstRow)
            With .Borders(wdBorderBottom)
                .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
                .Visible = True
                .LineWidth = wdLineWidth150pt
            End With
            With .Borders(wdBorderTop)
                .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
                .Visible = True
                .LineWidth = wdLineWidth150pt
            End With
            With .Font
                .Bold = False
                .Size = 12
                .Name = "Times New Roman"
            End With

        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

But there don't seems to have vba access to vertical alignment.

Comment: Right... the vertical alignment is the last part I'm uncertain on... if no one figures out a way to set it in a style, or if you modify your answer to include their solution, I will accept this answer... I appreciate the help and advice!

Comment: @JasonR.Mick It doesn't appear to be available through the object model, although it can be done when creating a style through the Word UI. Any chance you could use a Word template (dotx or dotm) that contains the style already? Create a new document from the template and the style will automatically be "inherited".

Comment: Hi Cindy, my current workaround is the following: `Sub AlignVertical(tblNew As Table, rows As Integer)
   Dim rowIdx As Integer
   For rowIdx = 1 To rows
      tblNew.rows(rowIdx).Cells.VerticalAlignment = wdCellAlignVerticalCenter
   Next rowIdx
End Sub` It isn't quite as tidy/homogeneous as I'd like, but it does the trick.  I use a similar function for table height: `Sub SetHeight(tblNew As Table, h As Single, rows As Integer)
   Dim rowIdx As Integer
   For rowIdx = 1 To rows
      tblNew.rows(rowIdx).SetHeight h, wdRowHeightExactly
   Next rowIdx
End Sub`  Seemed the best option.